# openLDAP cn=config doesn't seem to be configured correctly

Tags: openldap

I'm new to LDAP's, but have an openLDAP config which I have moved to using olc instead of the slapd.conf.

When I run the command

`ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b "" -LLL "configContexts"`

I get the empty result `dn:`

Does this suggest the config isn't working?  I was unable to use the `-H` to authenticate until I imported an ldif setting `{1}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth manage by * break` into `olcDatabase={0}config` under `olcAccess`, so I think that was done correctly.  But now that I add other ACL's, none of them seem to take.

Is the empty result from the configContexts command a concern?

This is all to get something like the following to work so I can set admins over the LDAP.

`{3}to * by dn.exact=uid=myadminaccount,dc=domain,dc=com manage by * break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to query attribute *configContext* (without trailing 's').

Provided you access control rules allow the bound entity to read it the result looks like this:

```
$ ldapsearch -H ldap://-s base -b "" -LLL "configContext"
dn:
configContext: cn=config
```